# Relative paths for include files in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Structure is this:

```
subsystem
  sub_dir
  sub_dir
  ...
  new_sub_dir_for _unit_test_which_includes_eclipse_workspace 
     Debug       <===   this, I think, being  ${workspace_loc} 
                        or is the parent directory ${workspace_loc}?
                        (since it contains .project and  .cproject)
     test_cases
     stubs
  file_1.c
  file_1.h
  file_1.c
  file_1.h
  ...
  software_under_test.c
  software_under_test.h
```

`software_under_test.c` says `#include "../somefile.h"`, which is obviously outside of this subsystem.

When I am setting up my include path with `Properties/C & C++ general/paths and symbols`, I can't seem to use a relative path, only an absolute, which I do not want to do, as I want others to be able to build this project on their machines and the start of the path can vary per user.

I did try adding `${workspace_loc}../` and variations thereof, but I can't get it work.

What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the variables option while browsing for location?

When adding an include file path in the CDT project (Project Properties/C/C++ General/Paths and Symbols), there are 3 options to browse for a location:

- Variables
- Workspace
- File system

Choose the Workspace option, the path will be relative to the workspace/project. Select the Variables option, you'll get to use variables such as `${WorkspaceDirPath}`. You should be able to even reference environment variables.

Comment: I accepted this answer almost two years ago, so it certainly worked then. Since that time I have forgotten how to use the solution for realtive paths :-(  Neither `${WorkspaceDirPath}../foo`, nor `${WorkspaceDirPath:../foo} seem to work. Any idea what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: Aha! Got it!  `${WorkspaceDirPath}/../foo`